# Computing loss only on missing pixels for image inpainting

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision

I'm trying to understand the image inpainting landscape, and I'm seeing 2 (of possibly more) strategies that I'd like to explore further.

1. Deep Image Prior (DIP) based methods, which don't train a model, but try to overfit a randomly initialized model on the known set of pixels in the image and rely on the fact that the trained weights resulting from those known pixels will somehow be able to provide a good approximation for the unknown pixels. In the case of the DIP model, I see that the loss is computed only on the set of pixels that is not missing. https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/deep-image-prior/blob/master/inpainting.ipynb `total_loss = mse(out * mask_var, img_var * mask_var)`
2. Deep Learning (DL) based methods which train (for example) a CNN model on a lot of images with parts of the image removed, and train a model that can predict the missing pixels. I'd like to know if the current state of the art uses a loss function on *all* on the predicted pixels (both known and missing) or if the loss function is computed only on the set of missing pixels (effectively making the loss function look at the opposite set of pixels that the loss for DIP methods look at).

Is there any prior research done in this direction and are there any results available?